# Adding Property Into Existed Class/Control

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

How Can I Add to picturebox control new property named "`defaultControl`"? (Type Of Control),
and use this new property like: `PictureBox1.defaultControl = dc`.

(**what is the Easiest/Fastest way to do it**)

Comment: use the existing `.Tag` property?  Otherwise subclass `PictureBox` and add those additional properties.

Comment: @Plutonix thanks, i can use it, but what if i want to use more than 1 property?

Comment: Why did you tag your post both C# and VB?

Comment: @SteveWellens because that i will accept any answer even if then code is .net i will convert him to c#...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A control is just a class that derives directly or indirectly from `System.Windows.Forms.Control`. You can create a new class that inherits from `PictureBox` and add it a new property as you would do it with any other class.

Your new `Control` will automatically appear in the toolbox within the current project and is ready to be used as any other `Control`. You can also change the type of your `PictureBox` to `PictureBoxEx` manually in the `Form1.Designer.cs` file. Close the designer and save the form before you make any changes to the `*.Designer.cs` file.

**VB**

```vb
Public Class PictureBoxEx
    Inherits PictureBox

    Private m_DefaultControl As Control
    Public Property DefaultControl() As Control
        Get
            Return m_DefaultControl
        End Get
        Set
            m_DefaultControl = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Starting with VS 2010 you can use [Auto-Implemented Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx)

```vb
Public Property DefaultControl As Control
```

**C#**

```cs
public class PictureBoxEx : PictureBox
{
    public Control DefaultControl { get; set; }
}
```

---

Extending existing controls is a very powerful way of creating new controls in winforms. You can override existing methods; add new properties, methods and events. Derive a control from `Control` if you want to create a completely new control or start with an existing control in order to change its behavior and look or if you want to add new functionality.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to extend the `PictureBox` class:

```
public class MyPictureBox : PictureBox
{
    public Control DefaultControl {get; set;}
}
```

You *can*, however, use the `Tag` property to attach an object to a control (for whatever reason):

```
PictureBox1.Tag = dc;
```